# dropdown does not appear after tapping icon-button in a scaffold toolbar

Tags: polymer

How to implement a dropdown in a scaffold toolbar?
I'm trying

```
<template is="auto-binding">
  <div relative tool>
   <core-icon-button id="sonst" icon="more-vert"></core-icon-button>
   <core-dropdown relatedTarget="{{$.sonst}}" halign="right" valign="top">
    <core-menu>
     <core-item>Einstellungen</core-item>
     <core-item>Hilfe</core-item>
     <core-item>Impressum</core-item>
   </core-menu>
  </core-dropdown>
 </div>
</template>
```

The icon-button is shown in the toolbar but the dropdown to not unfold on tap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought too simple. Another developer has pointed me to a solution. Thanks Michael.

Use "on-tap" and "this.$.drop.toggle()"
or a variable opened="{{opened}}"

```
  <polymer-element name="x-test" >
  <template>
  <div relative tool>
   <core-icon-button id="sonst" icon="more-vert" on-tap="{{toggle}}"></core-icon-button>
   <core-dropdown id="drop" opened="{{opened}}" relatedtarget="{{$.sonst}}" halign="left" valign="top">
    <core-menu>
     <core-item>Einstellungen</core-item>
     <core-item>Hilfe</core-item>
     <core-item>Impressum</core-item>
   </core-menu>
  </core-dropdown>
 </div>
  </template>
     <script>
Polymer({
  toggle: function() {
      this.$.drop.toggle();
    //this.opened = !this.opened;
  }
});
```

﻿